# return new Model result from JS to xml in odoo

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo-8, odoo-10

I'm trying to get value from python function and assign that value to xml coulmn,

**JS function called in xml :**

```
  var Users = new openerp.web.Model('res.users');
                var im = new openerp.im_chat.InstantMessaging(self);
                Users.call('has_group', ['base.group_user']).done(function(is_employee) {
                        alert(is_employee);
                        return is_employee;
                });
```

How can i return the "is_employee" value to xml field ? Now it always shows undefined in field, but alert prints value. Please anyone help me

Comment: it is not possible because it is deferred object. you need to manage it by promise

Comment: Can you give me an example for promise deferred object ?

Comment: it differs as per scenario can you update exact code in question ??